# Calling db.system.js Function in $where

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, mongodb-query

As a basic example, I have this function saved:

```
db.system.js.save({_id: "sum", value: function (x, y) { return x + y; }});
```

But when I try to called in the $where I get a Reference not exist.

```
<?php

$collection = $link -> selectCollection('foo' ,'bar');
$collection -> find(array(
'$where' =>'sum(this.x, this.y)'
));

?>
```

And the error

```
ReferenceError: sum is not defined :
```

Should I save it or access it another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you connecting to the same database namespace in your PHP code that you connected to using the shell? I think not!

Anyway you misunderstand the concept of [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) in this context, since you can only **evaluate** and not **return** modified results other than the data already contained in the collection.

The only things that can actually return something different than the existing documents are [`.mapReduce()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) and [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).

So to demonstrate, in the "same namespace" if you define a collection:

```js
db.djunk.insert({ "x": 1, "y": 2 })
```

And then run a `.mapReduce()`

```js
db.dbjunk.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(this._id, sum(this.x,this.y))
    },
    function() {}, // does nothing here where already unique
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

That would **return** an actual summed result:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("571a9bb951d042a7a896fd92"),
    "value" : 3
}
```

All that `$where` can do, is "logically" select the document:

```js
db.djunk.find(function() {
    return sum(this.x,this.y) > 3
})
```

Which would not meet the condition.

But of course you really don't need to do this, and should generally be avoiding any server execution of JavaScript where possible. It's much slower than native operators, and you can do quite a bit with native operators.

So instead of `.mapReduce()` call `.aggregate()`:

```js
db.djunk.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "total": { "$add": [ "$x", "$y" ] }
    }}
])
```

And instead of JavaScript evaluation, call `.aggregate()` again, with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) for "logical" filtering:

```js
db.djunk.aggregate([
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": { "$gt": [ { "$add": [ "$x", "$y" ] }, 3 ] },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }      
    }}
])
```

So in most cases there is always a better alternative to using JavaScript evaluation. And certainly there are actually very few cases to really need server stored functions in the cases where JavaScript evaluation is actually required.

But your basic error here will be because the function was in a different namespace, or indeed that you restarted the server in between. But the overall point is you probably should not be using stored functions anyway.

Comment: I was trying to use $project before A question I have is why is there a $ in front of all variables?

Comment: Because it's an "expression". This is how MongoDB identifies things that either refer to "document properties" or are otherwise "operators". So it's the reason why you cannot name a document property key starting with `$`, since this is actually reserved. In the context of inside the `$add`, think of the `$` on the properties just like `this`. There is actually the "longer form" for `$x`, being either `$$CURRENT.x` or `$$ROOT.x`, which both "look a lot like" the `this` notation of JavaScript.